# How is micro debris cleaned from the eye in unusual cases?

Tags: eye, glaucoma

Sometimes micro debris or "microparticles" are interacting with human's (and animals's) eyes:

It can be some types of dust or hair pieces trimmed with a trimmer; I especially mean little particles of matter that can rarely be seen without lots of light and/or common magnifying tools such as magnifying glass (hand lens).

I know that in an healthy person without glaucoma, for example, liquids such as excessive water would be pumped off the eye, but I'm not sure that counts things likes trimmed hair, etc.

> How is micro debris cleaned from the eye in unusual cases?

Google searches of:

```
How does the eye clean itself?
How is debris cleaned from the eye?
How is micro debris cleaned from the eye in unusual cases?
```

didn't bring any direct answer on this question besides some data on the eye cleaning itself in blink and while a human sleeps by tears. Also, I learned that humans have three types of [eye tears:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tears#Types) Basal, Reflex and Emotional; the first two are clearly protective.

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. This helps to provide an answer which will be more helpful. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: I have seen some questions here without prior research at all kept and well accepted. Where were you then?...

Comment: The odd question may slip through the net, and you may see a great number of questions I have placed this comment on if you care to look. If you are referring to questions which are a few years old, this requirement was not followed so strictly in the past, but you will find many questions closed by the community more recently due to lack of research. Including old questions. Feel free to flag old questions for closure.

Comment: @JohnDoea Chris is right. You might find old questions that lack prior research. If you do, flag them. But it is a requirement for all questions since the site's scope change in 2017.

Comment: [The very first result in Google for “How does the eye clean itself?”](https://kidshealth.org/en/kids/eyes.html) leads you to a kids health page I’ll grant you, but it does give an answer. Can you please elaborate on why you think this doesn’t directly answer your question?

Comment: @ChrisRogers I have seen this result but I assumed kids-oriented stuff isn't what I am looking for and will not cover all relevant terminology in anatomy and physiology.

Comment: Well, I am checking the page now --- I am impressed my assumption was wrong ; I think I will generally not use it again...